# Cannot install desktop docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-exec

I tried to install different versions of docker desktop, everything is configured properly, but whenever I launched an exe file, the installer terminanted the process and complained that windows version on my laptop is kind of improper. Versions (3.0.0, 2.5.0 and 2.3.0.3) left this message: "Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (16299+) or Windows 10 Home (18362.1040+)", though I definitely have this proper latest Windows 10 Home version on my machine. Older versions of docker did not support windows 10 home at all.
So the question is how can I get Docker Desktop installed on my computer?

Comment: What exact version of Windows Home do you have installed?

Comment: Also, try installing the Edge version.

Comment: Make sure that you've got latest windows updates. I installed Docker for desktop yesterday and everything works on Windows 10 Home OS compilation 19042.685.